# Understanding the mathematical expression of cost function

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, logistic-regression

It is very naive of me, but I am not able to get this expression for cost function:

```
||y - Xw||^2_2 + alpha * ||w||^2_2
```

What does the 2_2 mean? It is mentioned on [Scikit-Learn web page.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html)

Comment: For the LaTeX formatted output check [this](https://arachnoid.com/latex/?equ=%7C%7Cy%20-%20Xw%7C%7C%5E2_2%20%2B%20alpha%20*%20%7C%7Cw%7C%7C%5E2_2) out.

Answer (score 2):

It's `L2` norm squared. For two vectors it is their Euclidean distance squared. For single vector it is distance from origin squared. You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm).
In this case first term gives mean squared loss and the second term is `L2` regularization loss.